# How to set custom icon for UITableview row action buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uitableviewrowaction

How to set custom image icons for UItablebview rowactions? Currently i tried acheiving it by setting the rowaction background image using patternimage, but it is of no use.
And then i had created a custom icon font file with all the request icons and tried setting the rowaction title using this custom font.But this was also not successful. Could someone tell me how to set these icons for rowactions?
Tried looking at many online blogs and posts,but they are not that helpful to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following lib https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell . 
It allows to set images and titles for row actions

Answer (score -2):

You can set the `accessoryView` of `UITableViewCell`. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do following.

```
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]]
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,30,30); //Your custom frame to be set here
cell.accessoryView = imgView; //cell is your your cell object
```

Make sure if you are using UITableViewCell object instead of your own custom cell, Cell style should be set to `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`.